# Реализация после двойного щелчка мыши

Tags: css

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как в css узнать двойной щелчок левой клавишей мыши? Т.е. одинарный щелчок это `active`, а вот если дважды? Спасибо!

Comment: В `css` - никак.

Comment: В `css` нет событий кликов, но есть `active` и `hover` псевдоклассы,с которыми как-раз и можно сделать подобно `click`, но будут они работать и по правой и по левой и по колесику мышки. `active` работает когда нажали на элемент, а `hover`, когда навели мышкой на элемент.

Comment: @user250973, https://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSDoubleClick/